# How to set up Visual Regression of react-chartjs-2 component

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, jsdom, react-chartjs

I am trying to set up visual regression testing for react-chartjs-2 components with React Testing library. However, all of the snapshots that are being generated are blank, but the component renders properly in the browser.

This is what I'm currently testing. I basically combined this blog post [example](https://blog.logrocket.com/automated-visual-regression-testing-with-jest/) with the pie chart example from [react-chartjs-2](https://react-chartjs-2.netlify.app/examples/pie-chart).

```
import React from 'react';
import {generateImage, debug} from 'jsdom-screenshot';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react';
import {Pie} from "react-chartjs-2";

it('has no visual regressions', async () => {
    window.ResizeObserver =
        window.ResizeObserver ||
        jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
            disconnect: jest.fn(),
            observe: jest.fn(),
            unobserve: jest.fn(),
        }));

    const data = {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
            },
        ],
    };
    render(<div><Pie data={data}/></div>)
    expect(await generateImage()).toMatchImageSnapshot();
});
```

I am wondering if it's a timing issue. Running `debug()` before the expect shows a canvas with 0 width and height:

```
<canvas
  height="0"
  role="img"
  style="display: block; box-sizing: border-box; height: 0px; width: 0px;"
  width="0"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

The charting library you're using, `react-chartjs-2`, wraps `chart.js`, which relies on the `canvas` element to render charts to the screen. It's important to note that canvas contents are *not* part of the DOM, but are instead rendered virtually on top of a single DOM `canvas` element.

Keeping that in mind, take a look at how `jsdom-screenshot` renders images (from the explanation of method):

> We use jsdom to obtain the state of the HTML which we want to take a screenshot of. Consumers can use jsdom to easily get components into the state they want to take a screenshot of. jsdom-screenshot then uses the markup ("the HTML") at that moment (of that state). jsdom-screenshot launches a local webserver and serves the obtained markup as index.html. It further serves assets provided through serve so that local assets are loaded. Then jsdom-screenshot uses puppeteer to take a screenshot take screenshots of that page using headless Google Chrome.

When you call `generateImage()`, the HTML you posted (just an empty `canvas` element) is copied into a file, `index.html`, opened in Puppeteer, then a screenshot is taken. Because `canvas` elements don't include their contents in their markup, when the HTML is copied into a file the chart is lost.

In short, `jsdom-screenshot` **does not support drawing on `canvas` elements**.

I would recommend checking out [jest-puppeteer](https://github.com/smooth-code/jest-puppeteer), which runs your entire test suite inside of Puppeteer. Instead of using a virtualized DOM implementation `jsdom`, it will use the actual Chromium DOM implementation, which has the added benefit of functioning closer to runtime usage. You can use [`page.screenshot()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions) to take a screenshot of the chart exactly as it appears in-browser, with full DOM support (`canvas` included). Check out the `jest-puppeteer` README to get started.

Answer (score 0):

In order to test `react-chartjs-2` with jest and jsdom you don't need to mock the component or mock the canvas rendering.
You can do visual regression testing of the react components.
I am using:

```
chart.js v4.4.0
react-chartjs-2 v5.2.0
jsdom v19.0.0
jsdom-screenshot v4.0.0
jest v27.4.3
jest-image-snapshot v5.2.0
@jest/globals v27.4.2
@testing-library/jest-dom v5.16.0
@testing-library/react v12.1.2
```

and in my `jest.config.js` I have:

```
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
setupFilesAfterEnv: [
  '<rootDir>/jest.setup.afterEnv.js',
],
```

and in my `jest.setup.afterEnv.js` I have:

```
import { expect } from '@jest/globals';

import { configureToMatchImageSnapshot } from 'jest-image-snapshot';

const toMatchImageSnapshot = configureToMatchImageSnapshot({
  failureThresholdType: 'pixel',
  customSnapshotsDir: `${__dirname}/test/snapshots/`,
});

// extend Jest expect
expect.extend({ toMatchImageSnapshot });
```

With the setup above I can get an image out of the jest test of a generic `<Canvas />` component.

```
const getCanvasSnapshot = (canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, failureThreshold = 0) => {
  const image = canvas.toDataURL();
  const data = image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');
  const snapshot = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');

  expect(snapshot).toMatchImageSnapshot({ failureThreshold });
};

describe('<Canvas />', () => {
  test('render into canvas', () => {
    // @see https://medium.com/@pdx.lucasm/canvas-with-react-js-32e133c05258
    const Canvas = (props: any) => {
      const { draw, ...rest } = props;
      const canvasRef = React.useRef(null);

      React.useEffect(() => {
        const canvas = canvasRef.current as unknown as HTMLCanvasElement;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        draw(context);
      }, [draw]);

      return <canvas ref={canvasRef} {...rest} />;
    };

    const App = () => {
      const draw = (ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) => {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#0000ff';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(50, 50, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
      };

      return <Canvas draw={draw} width={100} height={100} />;
    };

    const { container } = render(<App />);

    const canvas = container.querySelector('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    getCanvasSnapshot(canvas);
  });
});
```

Extending this to `react-chartjs-2` is then simple. Couple issues that I had.
In browser mode the Chart can get its size from the parent container but when jest is running, the Chart could not get a size.
So I had to set

```
options.responsive = false; // only when jest is running
```

The setting of `options.maintainAspectRatio` was invariant to my application.

Then I had to set a width and height directly on the Chart component

```
  return (
    <Chart
      {...(isJestRunning() ? { width: '198' } : {})}
      {...(isJestRunning() ? { height: '202' } : {})}
      type="scatter"
      data={data as ChartData}
      options={options as ChartOptions}
      plugins={plugins}
    />
  );
```

Then the jest/jsdom test would produce an image. Note that `<Plot />` is just a simple wrapper around `<Chart />`.

```
describe('<Plot />', () => {
  let Wrapper: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    window.ResizeObserver =
      window.ResizeObserver ||
      jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        disconnect: jest.fn(),
        observe: jest.fn(),
        unobserve: jest.fn(),
      }));

    // wrap the code with hooks; otherwise we get
    // Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    Wrapper = () => (
      <Plot
        xScale={{ type: 'linear', min: 0, max: 1 }}
        yScale={{ type: 'linear', min: 0, max: 1 }}
        ...
        ...
      />
    );
  });

  afterEach(cleanup);

  test('render component', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Wrapper />);

    const canvas = container.querySelector('canvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;

    // make sure the canvas has the correct size
    expect(canvas.width).toEqual(198);
    expect(canvas.height).toEqual(202);

    // get an image of the canvas
    getCanvasSnapshot(canvas);
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.